# Entity Framework code first many-to-many relationship not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We're using Entity Framework 6, code first, to store a complex tree of objects that look like the following:

```
public abstract class DataCode
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class InternCode : DataCode
{
    public string PrimaryRelationalOperator { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryValue { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryRelationalOperator { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryValue { get; set; }
}

public class Model : DataCode
{
    public ICollection<string> Aliases { get; set; }
    public bool ExportOnly { get; set; }
    public void GetOptions()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Version
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public float VersionNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual PriceLevel PriceLevel { get; set; }
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Model> Models { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InternCode> DataReleaseLevels { get; set; }
}
```

So, a `Version` can refer to many `Model`s, each of which is a `DataCode`.  But another `Version` can refer to the same set of `Model`s (hence the `virtual` keyword, which *I think* is the way you do this).  A `PriceLevel` is also a `DataCode`.  A `Version` can also have many `InternCode`s, each of which is a `DataCode`, but that's another story.  At any rate, there's a lot going on in the `DataCode` table that EF generates.

We have the following **DataInitializer** code:

```
var ModelList = new List<Model>
{
    new Model { Code = "001-230", Description = "Model 230" },
    new Model { Code = "001-231", Description = "Model 231" },
    new Model { Code = "001-232", Description = "Model 232" },
    new Model { Code = "001-233", Description = "Model 233" },
    // and many more
}

var versions = new List<Entities.Version>
{
    new Entities.Version {
        VersionNumber=2.1F,
        Description = "Version 2.1 for Model Group A",
        EffectiveDate = DateTime.Parse("1/15/1995"),
        Models=new List<Model> { 
            ModelList.Find( m => m.Code == "001-230"),
            ModelList.Find( m => m.Code == "001-231"),
            ModelList.Find( m => m.Code == "001-232"),
            ModelList.Find( m => m.Code == "001-233"),
        },
        Status = "Draft"
   },
   new Entities.Version {
       VersionNumber=2.2F,
       Description = "Version 2.2 for Model Group A",
       EffectiveDate = DateTime.Parse("7/15/1995"),
       Models=new List<Model> { 
           ModelList.Find( m => m.Code == "001-230"),
           ModelList.Find( m => m.Code == "001-231"),
           ModelList.Find( m => m.Code == "001-232"),
           ModelList.Find( m => m.Code == "001-233"),
       },
       Status = "Draft"
   },
   new Entities.Version {
       VersionNumber=2.3F,
       Description = "Version 2.3 for Model Group A",
       EffectiveDate = DateTime.Parse("1/15/1996"),
       Models=new List<Model> { 
           ModelList.Find( m => m.Code == "001-230"),
           ModelList.Find( m => m.Code == "001-231"),
           ModelList.Find( m => m.Code == "001-232"),
           ModelList.Find( m => m.Code == "001-233"),
       },
       Status = "Draft"
   }                            
};
```

After saving changes, sacrificing a chicken, and all the other stuff, we're finding that the **DataCode** table in the database is creating two columns named `Version_VersionId` and `Version_VersionId1`.  The first has null values, the second has the `Id` of the last `Version` record that was created.  At the very least, I would expect that it would create a new `Version_VersionId` column for each `Version` that `Model` was a member of.  This seems horribly inefficient to me, but at least it would work.  Instead, the data seems to be stomping on previous `Version` references.

I'm hoping we can fix this with FluentAPI, but I have no idea how.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before starting, after solved the problem, take also care about `public ICollection<string> Aliases { get; set; }` because can't be mapped in this way.

The context is very important. For me is quite strange that you have a DataCode table (DataCode class is abstract so you - and EF - can't create it).
Anyway, using this context

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext(DbConnection connection) : base(connection, true) { }

    public DbSet<InternCode> InternCodes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Model> Models { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Version> Versions { get; set; }


}
```

Three table are created as expected. InternCode has a Version_Id and Model has a Version_Id because you did not specify anything on Model and InternCode about version so EF assumes that one InternCode (and one Model) has only one Version

To achieve that a single Model (and a single InternCode) can be related to more than one version you can do the following:

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext(DbConnection connection) : base(connection, true) { }

    public DbSet<InternCode> InternCodes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Model> Models { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Version> Versions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new VersionMap());
    }
}

public class InternCode : DataCode
{
    public string PrimaryRelationalOperator { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryValue { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryRelationalOperator { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryValue { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Version> Versions { get; set; }
}

public class Model : DataCode
{
    public ICollection<string> Aliases { get; set; }
    public bool ExportOnly { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Version> Versions { get; set; }
    public void GetOptions()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


public class VersionMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Version>
{
    public VersionMap()
    {
        // Relationships
        HasMany(t => t.Models)
            .WithMany(t => t.Versions);

        HasMany(t => t.DataReleaseLevels)
            .WithMany(t => t.Versions);
    }
}
```

In this case you'll see several tables created (the tables to express n to m relationships)

Comment: We noticed that Aliases wasn't working as expected (or at all).  What can we do to resolve the problem?  Do we need to create `public class Alias` with `public long Id` and `public string Alias` as properties?

Comment: You can do it or, if you don't need to search by Aliases, you can add a private store field (need to map it via fluent interface and the mapping class must be an inner class of the entity) and use it to compile Aliases.